# New Line in prettier when more then one attribute and content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prettier

i want to add config to not break line when length is less than printWidth property.

**First Case**

input:

```
<div b={2} a={2} b={3} c={22}>s</div>
```

output:

```
<div b={2} a={2} b={3} c={22}>
        s
</div>
```

**Second Case**

input:

```
 <div b={2} a={2} b={3} c={22}></div>
```

output:

```
<div b={2} a={2} b={3} c={22}></div>
```

**Third Case**

input:

```
<div b={2} a={2}>a</div>
```

output:

```
<div b={2} a={2}>
   a
</div>
```

expected:

```
<div b={2} a={2}>a</div>
```

Comment: Prettier is _opinionated_ with [a limited number of options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options), so it's unlikely you'll be able to configure it to your requirements.

Comment: It seems that there is no such option, what is interesting is that it formats plain HTML and angular templates as you want, but not jsx.